# How to detect window resizing in Mac Catalyst?

Tags: swift, uiwindow, mac-catalyst

How can I a get a notification when user resize the window while:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(function), name: NSWindowDidResizeNotification, object: nil)
```

is unavailable in Mac Catalyst

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just like in iOS. Use [`windowScene(_:didUpdate:interfaceOrientation:traitCollection:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscenedelegate/3198094-windowscene) in your window scene delegate, or implement [`viewWillTransition(to:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition) in your view controllers.

Comment: And if it doesn't always seem to be resizing, especially when trying fullscreen, wrap whatever you are updating in `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`.

Comment: What if you're not using scenes in your app?

Comment: @Oscar Did you miss the second part of the answer?

Comment: Hi Leo. Will try that ASAP.

Comment: I implemented my scaling calculations in viewWillTransitionTo and it works fine.