# How can I detect my app’s windows size changing in Mac OS?

Tags: ios, macos, uiview, drawing

I’m an iOS/iPad app developer, and now that my app runs on Mac OS I’m seeing an issue where the user can freely change the size of the app’s frame, resulting in UI issues with my custom UIVew drawing code. Is there a way to register for a notification of some kind, so I can do a screen layout update?

Answer (score 0):

If you develop under macOS, you should most probably use `NSWindow`, so in that case you can subcribe to `NSWindowDidResizeNotification`. More details here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdidresizenotification

Also you can use UIWindowDelegate [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscenedelegate/3198094-windowscene) - also can check related to this method and the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58159414/how-to-detect-window-resizing-in-mac-catalyst)

Comment: I actually develop under iOS, as mentioned. So I am not sure those methods apply